# PyQt4 problem with xml database browser (treeview, singals and insertplaintext)

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4

I'm writing a database browser application with PyQt4 and because I'm new to Qt, I have some problems. I have most functionalities already written in python but know I'm trying to implement them with PyQt4 GUI.

First of all my application now looks like this:
[Browser](http://student.agh.edu.pl/~wysek/browser.png)
In these catalogues I have xml files which I would like to parse.
I've written something like this:

`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.treeView, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(QModelIndex)"), self.ui.plainTextEdit, QtCore.SLOT("paste()"))` 
and it works. But when I'm trying to do something like this:
`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.treeView, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(QModelIndex)"), self.ui.plainTextEdit, QtCore.SLOT("insertPlainText('test')"))`
it fails. After reading the manual I know that SIGNAL and SLOT must take the same arguments. So I should write some signal which executes a SLOT which is a function with QModelIndex argument which finds clicked file, creates the xmldocument object and then prints out it's dictionaries.
My questions are:

  How can I create such function which is callable as SLOT?

Because inside ui file I created a function:
`def test(self):
        print "Debug"`
And when I'm trying to call it out
`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.treeView, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(QModelIndex)"), self.ui.test())`
    
 I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:

  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'`
And another question:

  How should I get path to clicked file from QModelIndex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the new-style connection mechanism provided by PyQt:

```
self.ui.treeView.clicked.connect(self.ui.plainTextEdit.paste)
```

Now, `paste` is a method accepting a single argument, and this argument is of the type the `clicked` signal of `self.ui.treeView` sends. Dissect if from there, as you wish.

---

*How can I create such function which is callable as SLOT?*

It's a different error. You connect to `self.ui.test()`, but this is **a function call**, not a function. Remove the `()` after `test`. But better yet, use the new-style connection mechanism as described above.

---

*How should I get path to clicked file from QModelIndex?*

Probably by calling its `data` method. Read the [doc for `QModelIndex`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmodelindex.html)